# Передать пароль при подключении по websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

Рефакторим один легаси проект.
 В нем таким вот образом устанавливается вэбсокет соединение между node.js middleware и сервером на django:

```
const WebSocket = require('faye-websocket');
import CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const token = CryptoJS.MD5(login);
const WS_URL = `ws://${token}@${api_rest_server}/ws/channel/test`;
const ws = new WebSocket.Client(WS_URL);
ws.on('open', (event) => { ...
```

В результате фактически устанавливается соединение по url:

```
`ws://${api_rest_server}/ws/channel/test`
```

и в качестве параметра передается что-то вроде

```
{
  login: token,
  password: api_rest_server,
}
```

и сервер на django авторизует желающих подключиться, используя этот payload.
 
 Теперь возникла необходимость подключаться к django через вэбсокет напрямую из вэб-приложения. Подключить на клиенте библиотеку faye-websocket не получается, т.к. она под капотом подключает встроенные node.js пакеты, которых нет в браузере.
 
 Есть ли возможность подобным образом передать вместе с событием connection параметры login, password при использовании нативных вэбсокетов, библиотеки socket.io?

Comment: проще передавать токен в урле, а на сервере сделать в роутерах мидлваре, которая проверяет валидность. `wss://host/api/v1/TOKEN/channel/test` или `wss://host/ws/TOKEN/channel/test`

Comment: твой вопрос обсудили [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api) и во втором ответе там упоминают Bearer